# Python for loop execution very slow ! How to make better

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a hyperspectral picture img_1, it shape is (609,460,233), and And I drew ROI on this picture (6 ROIs). Now I need to get pixels through For-loop. Use code:

```
X_train = np.empty((0,233)).astype(np.uint16)
y_train = np.empty((0,1)).astype(np.uint16)

for i in range (0,Mask_ROI.shape[0]):
    if (i%20 == 0): print(i)
    for j in range (0,Mask_ROI.shape[1]):
        for k in range(1,6):
            if (Mask_ROI[i,j] ==k):
                tmp = img_1[i,j,:].reshape(1,233)
                X_train = np.vstack((X_train,tmp))
                y_train = np.vstack((y_train,k))
        if (Mask_bk[i,j] == 1):
            tmp = img_1[i,j,:].reshape(1,233)
            X_train = np.vstack((X_train,tmp)) 
            y_train = np.vstack((y_train,22))
```

The result will be like this df：
[image: 1]

But the execution of this For-loop is very slow. How can I change it?

Comment: I suggest starting from [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual) your code to find which parts needs most time

Comment: Any time you're explicitly iterating over every element of an array, *you're not using numpy to its full extent*.  For example, `np.where(Mask_ROI == k)` would directly give you all the indices where the values equal `k`, allowing you to omit the `i` and `j` loops.

Comment: I have searched for relevant information and found that I can use "lamba" to solve this For-loop problem, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to analyze or build ML models, therefore you may need to consider each pixel from spatial information all through spectral information (233 features in your case) as a vector referring to the book [C.-I. Chang, Real-Time Recursive Hyperspectral Sample and Band Processing 2017].
Now you can simply reshape your array so that will be like a data frame ready for training (for loop is not required and I recommend you try to avoid it as much as possible for efficiency purpose).

```
dataset = np.reshape(Mask_ROI, (-1, 233))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply，But I got this error "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 280140 into shape (233)" after using this code！

Comment: Hi, You need to run it on your datacube. you will directly reshape your 3D data into a 2D df-like array.